# What's the best way to optimize accessing ManyToMany fields in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Video object with two ManyToMany fields. Each will contain a list of Users. I'm wondering how important it is to optimize so that there is only one db call when accessing a Video - or if there's even a way to do that. Also - i'll only be using the count of each of these ManyToMany fields - is it 'cheaper' to call Count() than to get the entire list then do 'length'?.

For example:

```
class Video(models.Model):
  ...
  dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True)
  likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True)
  ...
```

In my template for rendering a particular video object - I need the count for each of likes and dislikes. What's the performance optimal way to do that? It seems to me calling count() which results in two extra db calls is the best - but I'm not sure...

Comment: Are you sure that you need to store the `User` foreign key?

Comment: I assume he wants to make sure that each User can only vote once. That is why he needs the User reference. Is that correct, 9-bits?

Comment: @9-bits, **["Rule of Optimization: Prototype before polishing. Get it working before you optimize it"](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html)**. Or, in other words, **["We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" D. Knuth](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Program_optimization).** You **DONT** need to optimise every query before producing a working prototype. **This approach is ineffective**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

"Don't use len() on QuerySets if all you want to do is determine the number of records in the set. It's much more efficient to handle a count at the database level, using SQL's SELECT COUNT(*), and Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason."

There is another way you may want to go, instead of using count() as a separate operation, you may want to annotate the QuerySet with the count of likes/dislikes. Something like:

```
video = Video.objects.get(id=<video_id>).annotate(num_likes=Count('likes'), num_dislikes=Count('dislikes'))
```

This will get a Video object with `num_likes` and `num_dislikes` fields. You could use `filter()` or `all()` instead of `get()` to get multiple videos, each with a `num_likes` and `num_dislikes` field. In your template, you would have `{{ video.num_likes }}` and `{{ video.num_dislikes }}` to show these two annotated fields.

Comment: Interesting - if I do it that way (using annotate) is it a separate DB call or is that somehow all done in one call?

Comment: From my understanding, it is all in one call, using a group by clause.